# Do you disclose difficulty to the player before they decide to accept a GM-intrusion?

Tags: numenera

Normally, players have the option of spending 1 XP to reject a GM-intrusion.  How much information do the players have about the intrusion when deciding whether to accept or not? More specifically, do they know the difficulty of the intrusion?

When I offer an intrusion, I have been doing something like this:

> GM: As you begin digging through the rubble, it caves in on you! This is a GM-intrusion. You can reject it by spending 1 xp, or you can accept the difficulty 3 task and get some xp.

However, I am considering whether or not I should disclose the difficulty upfront, or keep it secret.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61674/is-the-task-difficulty-target-number-from-an-event-hidden-by-the-gm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the rules, the GM doesn't have to specify the target number or difficulty of a task. (*numenera* page 84)

> If the action still isn’t routine, the GM uses its difficulty to determine the target number—how high the player must roll to succeed at the action (see the Task Difficulty Chart, page 87). **The GM doesn’t have to tell the player what the target number is, but he can give her a hint**, especially if her character would reasonably know if the action was easy, average, difficult, or impossible.

However, that is up to your and your group's play style. Some people prefer to know their odds, others will prefer to live dangerously. Personally, i have played it both ways, and not knowing the exact difficult makes the game world feel more dangerous.